# How to turn-off the heuristic guessing of (kanji + okurigana) while doing Japanese input?

Tags: settings, input-source

The Japanese input method has changed on my Mac. The traditional way on *OSX* **and** *Windows* is:

1. type hiragana for the word;
2. press space bar;
3. use arrow keys to select (kanji + okurigana);
4. press enter.

Somehow, (95% sure this because of *El Capitan*) my input method has become:

1. start typing hiragana;
2. while still typing hiragana, it continues to take heuristic guesses at the (kanji + okurigana) that I might want. This approach makes most sense on mobile phones, but I don't want to do this on my MacBook!
3. pressing `esc` reverts the guessed (kanji + okurigana) back to only hiragana (what I want), but then type another hiragana, and it starts to guess again... this is driving me crazy.

What language settings do I need to adjust so that I can input Japanese as I always have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is indeed a [new feature for El Capitan](http://www.apple.com/osx/whats-new/):

> **Mac becomes even more fluent.**
>
> **Japanese**
>
> **Live conversion for keyboard input.**
>
> OS X El Capitan dramatically improves the ease and speed of entering Japanese text. With an enhanced vocabulary and improved language engine, it automatically transforms Hiragana into written Japanese as you type — eliminating the need to press the space bar for individual word conversions.

You can disable ***Live Conversion*** under `System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources > Japanese`, or the shortcut in the Input Menu Item by clicking `Open Japanese Preferences`:

[image]

Comment: this does not help me, if I type in hiragana for ogenki it changes it to kanji if i hit escape it goes back but if I try to put a space it makes it kanji again. This is very annoying for learning since I don't know kanji.

Comment: Pls inform us again if you find the solution for this.